# Writing a clean Predicate Builder

Tags: java

I have an inner class for filtering:

```
private class RegSpecification implements Specification<Reg> {

    private final transient RegFilterDTO filter;
    private transient Predicate predicate;
    private transient CriteriaBuilder cb;

    public RegSpecification(RegFilterDTO filter) {
        this.filter = filter;
    }

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Reg> root, CriteriaQuery<?> cq, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
        // this.cb = cb;
        this.predicate = cb.conjunction();

        Join<Reg, Acct> userJoin = root.join(acct, JoinType.INNER);

        predicate = eqEnumVal(predicate, cb, root.get(regType), RegType.class, filter.getRegType());
        predicate = eq(predicate, cb, userJoin.get(Acct_.id), filter.getAcctId());
        predicate = like(predicate, cb, root.get(regNumber), filter.getRegNumber());

        return predicate;
    }
}
```

And I made a helper class, to be used by other class as well who implements filtering by `Specification` (methods are public since some services are in other packages):

```
public class PredicateBuilder {

    public static Predicate like(Predicate predicate, CriteriaBuilder cb, Path<String> path, String value) {
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(value)) {
            return cb.and(predicate, cb.like(cb.lower(path), "%" + value.toLowerCase() + "%"));
        }
        return predicate;
    }

    public static <T> Predicate eq(Predicate predicate, CriteriaBuilder cb, Path<T> path, T value) {
        if (value != null) {
            return cb.and(predicate, cb.equal(path, value));
        }
        return predicate;
    }

    public static <T extends Enum<T>> Predicate eqEnumVal(Predicate predicate, CriteriaBuilder cb,
                                                          Path<T> path, Class<T> enumType, String name) {
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(name)) {
            return eq(predicate, cb, path, Enum.valueOf(enumType, name));
        }
        return predicate;
    }

}
```

**Question is**
Can I use private local variables in my RegSpecification so I won't have to use `predicate = ...` every time I call the helper class and some generic method to pass the predicate and cb to the helper class (so I won't have to pass the predicate and cb in my helper class methods)?

Where I could just do something like:

```
PredicateBuilder.with(predicate, cb)
   ...
   like(userJoin.get(Acct_.id), filter.getAcctId());
   eq(userJoin.get(Acct_.id), filter.getAcctId());
   like(root.get(regNumber), filter.getRegNumber());
   ...
.build();
```

in my `toPredicate` method.

Or any suggestions to make the code cleaner?

(Should I also annotate the helper class with `@Component`?)

Comment: Hi sophie. Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the question & answer style of Code Review. As such we have rolled back your latest edit. Please see [what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that the `PredicateBuilder` actually follows a builder like pattern, where methods are cascaded to create the object. Currently the `predicate` object is updated with seaparate calls to the static method in the `PredicateBuilder`. Rather than that you could follow the below approach which is more in line with a "builder".

```java
public class PredicateBuilder {

    private Predicate predicate;
    private CriteriaBuilder cb;
    private List<Consumer<PredicateBuilder>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
    
    private PredicateBuilder(){
    }
    
    public static PredicateBuilder with(Predicate p, CriteriaBuilder c) {
        PredicateBuilder instance = new PredicateBuilder();
        instance.predicate = p;
        instance.cb = c;
        return instance;
    }

    public PredicateBuilder tasks(List<Consumer<PredicateBuilder>> tasks) {
        this.tasks = tasks;
        return this;
    }

    public Predicate build() {
        for(Consumer<PredicateBuilder> task : tasks) {
            task.accept(this);
        }
        return this.predicate;
    }
    
    public PredicateBuilder like(Path<String> path, String value) {
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(value)) {
            CriteriaBuilder c = this.cb;
            this.predicate = c.and(this.predicate,
                                   c.like(c.lower(path), "%" + value.toLowerCase() + "%"));
        }
        return this;
    }

    public <T> PredicateBuilder eq(Path<T> path, T value) {
        if (value != null) {
            CriteriaBuilder c = this.cb;
            this.predicate = c.and(this.predicate, c.equal(path, value));
        }
        return this;
    }

    public <T extends Enum<T>> PredicateBuilder eqEnumVal(Path<T> path, Class<T> enumType, String name) {
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(name)) {
            return eq(path, Enum.valueOf(enumType, name));
        }
        return this;
    }

}
```

Then you could invoke as below:

```java
List<Consumer<PredicateBuilder>> tasks 
                    = List.of(pb -> pb.eqEnumVal(root.get(regType), RegType.class, filter.getRegType()),
                              pb -> pb.eq(userJoin.get(Acct_.id), filter.getAcctId()),
                              pb -> pb.like(root.get(regNumber), filter.getRegNumber()));
return PredicateBuilder.with(predicate, cb)
                       .tasks(tasks)
                       .build();
```

This way you could provide tasks if you want them to execute conditionally or directly invoke the methods.

Comment: Thank you! I am having trouble though with the tasks. I had to do `.tasks(new Runnable[] {...})` for it to compile. Also, I have warnings like: `Static member 'PredicateBuilder.tasks(java.lang.Runnable[])' accessed via instance reference` and 
`Static member 'PredicateBuilder.build()' accessed via instance reference`

Comment: @sophie I actually forgot to make a few changes. The `tasks` and `build` need not be static and the parameter to tasks should be `Runnable... tasks` instead of `Runnable[] tasks`. This would allow the comma separated list to be passed. I have made the edits to the answer. Please try now

Comment: Thank you Gautham. May I also know the use of thread/Runnable here?

Comment: @sophie Since Runnable represents a functional interface which takes no arguments and returns nothing, I had used runnable to keep the list of actions to be done. The actual method execution happens only when the `run` is invoked (inside `build`). In this way, the caller method could pass the list of actions to be done.

Comment: Oh. Thank you for the explanation! :)

Comment: I am having a problem with the instance being static - if I run 2 consecutive queries, the predicate are the same now.

Comment: @sophie I have  updated the code. Not much changes - instance and tasks are now removed. All methods except `with` are made `non-static`. Replace every usage of `instance` with `this` (except in the `with` method). And changes to how the builder is invoked. I believe it looks more clean than the first version. :-)

Comment: thank you, I have to `return this` (PredicateBuilder) with all this methods right? Also, I have conditional statements before in my tasks like:                  ` () -> { if (...) { otherPredicate(predicate); } },` how can I apply it given it is built with `.eq`

Comment: also I am having warnings again like: "static" members should be accessed statically, so instead of `with`, I replaced it with a constructor and assigned: `this.predicate = p;` and `this.cb = c;`

Comment: Hi Gautham M. Answers must make at least one [insightful observation](/help/how-to-answer), and must explain why the change is better than the OP's code.

Comment: @GauthamM sorry, the static issue is okay now, but any suggestions on how to incorporate conditional statements when calling the Predicate Builder's methods before calling `getPredicate()` ? I have IF-ELSE statements before when I used the Tasks, like`if () eq(..) else isNull(..)`

Comment: @sophie updated. you could do it using consumer instead of runnable. check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/12462079/7804477 to know why i used a list instead of varargs.